# How can I define the lower and upper boundaries of a range filter in google scripts/javascript by using variables?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter, range

I'm trying to run a function to create serial numbers similar to a dewey decimal system for a database using Google Sheets/Scripts. Most of the function works properly but the final portion (which should add +1 to the the serial number of whatever items already exist - essentially auto-incrementing similar items) is not working no matter what i try.

The idea is that the various categories all correspond to a digit of the serial number and the final 3 digits are reserved for the auto incrementing of similar items as they're added. The concept is to search the existing database for all currently existing serial numbers, then filter according to the specific range that the new item falls in, then find the highest value currently and add +1.

I will have to also add a way to start when the range doesn't exist yet but first i'm just trying to get the filter to work.

It works if I use manual inputs "1" for lower and "1000000000000" for upper but when i try to have my code define upper and lower, it doesn't work - even though my logs show the variables as being defined, they show an empty result.

```
function addNewFixtureRow(rowData) {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Serial");
  const db = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  const last = ws.getLastRow();
  const lastDb = db.getLastRow();
      const ms = ss.getSheetByName("Manufacturers");
    const lastMs = ms.getLastRow();
  const dataArray = [rowData.manufacturer,rowData.fixtureName,rowData.srcType,rowData.category,rowData.color,rowData.watts,rowData.volts];

       const data1 = ws.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();
            for(i=0;i<data1.length;++i){
              if (data1[i][1]==dataArray[2]){break};
            }
    const dataReturn1 = (data1[i][0]);        
    
    const data2 = ws.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();
            for(i=0;i<data2.length;++i){
              if (data2[i][1]==dataArray[3]){break};
            }
    const dataReturn2 = (data2[i][0]);
  
      const data3 = ws.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();
            for(i=0;i<data3.length;++i){
              if (data3[i][1]==dataArray[4]){break};
            }
    const dataReturn3 = (data3[i][0]);
     
    const dataReturn4 = (dataArray[5]/dataArray[6]);
  
      if (dataReturn4 <=0){
        var dataReturn5 =("");
      }
      else if (dataReturn4 <=2){
        var dataReturn5 = 100000;
      }
      else if (dataReturn4 <=6){
        var dataReturn5 = 200000;
      }
      else if (dataReturn4 <=15){
        var dataReturn5 = 300000;
      }
      else if (dataReturn4 <=42){
        var dataReturn5 = 400000;
      }
      else {
        var dataReturn5 = 500000;
      }

    const data6 = ms.getRange(1,4,lastMs,2).getValues();
            for(i=0;i<data6.length;++i){
              if (data6[i][1]==dataArray[0]){break};
            }
    const dataReturn6 = (data6[i][0]);
            
  const lowEnd = (dataReturn1 + dataReturn2 + dataReturn3 + dataReturn5 + dataReturn6).toString(10);
  const highEnd = (parseInt(lowEnd) + 99).toString(10);
  
  const database = db.getRange(2,1,lastDb,1).getValues();
  
  
  
  function isInRange(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'number') {
        return false;
    }
    return value >= this.lower && value <= this.upper;
}
  
  let data = database.flat();

let range = {
    lower: lowEnd,
    upper: highEnd
};

let numberInRange = data.filter(isInRange, range);
  
  
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(range);  
Logger.log(numberInRange);
  
var max = numberInRange.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
});
  Logger.log(max);
  var serialNumber = max + 1;
  
  db.appendRow([serialNumber,rowData.manufacturer,rowData.fixtureName,rowData.srcType,rowData.category,rowData.color,rowData.watts,rowData.volts]);
  
  return true;
  
}
```

[screenshot of Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUwzp.png)

Can I define the upper and lower boundaries of the search range with my variables or do they have to explicitly defined in the code? The whole code hinges on whether those boundaries are able to be defined according to calculations of the user inputs for the specific item. Any other way to do this in Google Scripts?

Comment: When I saw your log image, the values of `data` is `14315103101`, `14315203102` and `14315203103`. But the values of `lower` and `upper` are `14315303100` and `14315303199`. In this case, the values of `data` are not included in the range of the values of `lower` and `upper`. I thought that by this, `numberInRange` has not values. So I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? If you can do, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue and provide the sample output you expect?

Comment: When you filter `let numberInRange = data.filter(isInRange, range);` this array is empty as per the error, can you please share a Spreadsheet as example or an screenshot of how your data looks like?